# (need explanation) spout reader documentation

Tags: codeigniter, spout

can someone help me with this spout documentation,

```
use Box\Spout\Reader\Common\Creator\ReaderEntityFactory;

$reader = ReaderEntityFactory::createReaderFromFile('/path/to/file.ext');

$reader->open($filePath);

foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
    foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        // do stuff with the row
        $cells = $row->getCells();
        ...
    }
}

$reader->close();
```

what i don't get is :

1. What should i do with *('/path/to/file.ext')*
2. where do the $filePath come from ? do we need to create a variable named $filePath which will directing to the temporary uploaded file ?

I have read the docimentation and i still don't get it
I also tried to implement it with code igniter, here's my code :

require_once APPPATH.'third_party\spout\src\Spout\Autoloader\autoload.php';
use Box\Spout\Reader\Common\Creator\ReaderEntityFactory;

class Excel extends CI_Controller {

```
//==========================================================
// C O N S T R U C T O R
//==========================================================
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Excel_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $reader = ReaderEntityFactory::createReaderFromFile('/path/to/file.ext');
        $filePath = APPPATH.'third_party\spout\src\temp\test.xlsx';
        $reader->open($filePath);

        foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
            foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
                // do stuff with the row
                $cells = $row->getCells();
                echo $cells;
            }
        }

        $reader->close();   
    }   

}
```

and got this error message instead :

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Box\Spout\Common\Exception\UnsupportedTypeException

Message: No readers supporting the given type: ext

Filename: D:\ONNE\OTHERS\_CODING_PROGRAMMING\XAMPP\htdocs\bulus-ci\application\third_party\spout\src\Spout\Reader\Common\Creator\ReaderFactory.php

Line Number: 59

Backtrace:

File: D:\ONNE\OTHERS\_CODING_PROGRAMMING\XAMPP\htdocs\bulus-ci\application\third_party\spout\src\Spout\Reader\Common\Creator\ReaderFactory.php
Line: 42
Function: createFromType

File: D:\ONNE\OTHERS\_CODING_PROGRAMMING\XAMPP\htdocs\bulus-ci\application\third_party\spout\src\Spout\Reader\Common\Creator\ReaderEntityFactory.php
Line: 24
Function: createFromFile

File: D:\ONNE\OTHERS\_CODING_PROGRAMMING\XAMPP\htdocs\bulus-ci\application\controllers\Excel.php
Line: 20
Function: createReaderFromFile

File: D:\ONNE\OTHERS\_CODING_PROGRAMMING\XAMPP\htdocs\bulus-ci\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File path is a string pointing to the spreadsheet you're trying to read. You need to define it and pass it to Spout this way:

```
use Box\Spout\Reader\Common\Creator\ReaderEntityFactory;

$filePath = APPPATH.'third_party\spout\src\temp\test.xlsx';
$reader = ReaderEntityFactory::createReaderFromFile($filePath);
$reader->open($filePath);

foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
    foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        // do stuff with the row
        $cells = $row->getCells();
        ...
    }
}

$reader->close();
```

Can you give it a try?

Comment: yes, this works thanks a lot.
but one more question, when i tried to vardump the $cells the result was an object which is confusing , i don't kknow how to use it https://pastebin.com/R2cYNkNH

Comment: `$cell[0]->getValue()` returns the value in the first cell of the row. You can iterate through the cells with a simple `foreach ($cells as $cell) { ... }`.